# blockchain.com saying I do have enough funds

Tags: trading, payment

I have had 0.3097 of a BTC in a wallet for a couple of years. Needing to pay for something, I went into blockchain.com and entered the login link and password and the system showed me the balance which was correct. So far so good.

I then called up SEND and entered the balance (I want to send all the money in the wallet to a certain address). No matter what I enter in the amount box, red letters come up saying "insufficient funds".

What do I do ?

Comment: How did you receive the BTC? Was it in very small increments? You're sure its not a 'watch only' address? Do you have a mnemonic seed phrase for the wallet? You could recreate the wallet on another device and send from there (assuming this is a blockchain.info wallet bug)

Comment: The BTC was transferred into the wallet all in one go in December 2013. The wallet is a JC wallet and the details are held off line. I have a note saying that if you send money from this wallet, you have to send all the money to one or more destinations; you cannot send part of the money to an address and retain part of the money in the wallet. The wallet has to be "swept", my notes say.

Comment: What do you mean by 'JC' wallet? Is that the name of a service you used? It sounds like you have a paper wallet, and you need to sweep  the key (move the coins) to a new wallet in order to spend the funds. Did you 'import a private key' to the blockchain.info wallet? Or did you 'add an address'? There is a difference, and it may be why you're having issues.

Comment: I have now resolved this problem which was down to my unfamiliarity with the SEND form. Your comments appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you click send a modal window pops up. Look at the transaction fee in the bottom right of that. Deduct that from your balance and you'll be able to move your bitcoins.

Comment: All it says in the modal window is Transaction Fee = Regular and there is no actual number given anywhere. In any case I tried entering lesser sums. This wallet was originally created as a JC Wallet and the details kept off line. I have a note that this type of wallet must have all of the contained money sent to destination(s) and that you can't sent part of the money somewhere and keep part of it in the wallet.

Comment: I have now resolved this problem which was down to my mis-understanding the SEND form.